# Google chrome developer tools: Element selection based on css class

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a good resource on using console of Google chrome developer tools.

I see an introduction [here](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial#console) .

I have a specific qn about how to select HTML elements based on CSS class.

The above link shows how to select based on id (using $("") ).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok.. I figured it out.. similar to firebug, $$(".class")

Comment: Hey would you please add more info on your answer, above links are not valid anymore